# Access C# COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used

Tags: c#

I worked a lot but not solved this problem. I am making a program in c# with access database.

I added new form and I want to update database with this form.

I am getting id with this in another form;
            gelenid = Form1.id2;

This is my code. Im getting error in  komut.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
        isim = comboBox1.Text;
        yapilacak_is = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        bolum = comboBox2.Text.Trim();
        tarih = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
        durum = comboBox3.Text;
        int idm = Convert.ToInt32(gelenid);
        baglanti.Open();
        komut.Connection = baglanti;
        komut.CommandText = @"UPDATE Bakim SET [Ad]=@isim, 
                        [Bolum]=@bolum,
                        [Yapilacak_Is]=@yapis,          
                        [Tarih]=@tarihim,
                        [Durum]=@durum 
                        WHERE [Id]=@Id";

        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isim", isim);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yapis", yapilacak_is);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bolum", bolum);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarih", tarih);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@durum", durum);
        // Moved after the Cover parameter
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", idm);
        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
        baglanti.Close();

        komut.Dispose();
```

I added komut for command

OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=BakimVeritabani.accdb"); 
OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand();

Comment: You need to show how `komut` is created.  Also, you really should be using `using` blocks and not calling `.Dispose()` and `.Close()` maunally.

Comment: OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=BakimVeritabani.accdb");

        OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand();
        Form1 frmAna = (Form1)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"];

Comment: Never put code in comments, it should go in the question only and be properly formatted. You also need to show how the two relate to each other. Is baglanti being created in the function or do you have a single connection you keep reusing

Comment: I have one connection. I added first post my code.

Answer (score 0):

> I have one connection.

That is likely your problem, your connection likely can not handle being opened and closed multiple times, You should be making a new connection every time and disposing of it with a `using` statement.

```
using(OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=BakimVeritabani.accdb")
using(OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand())
{
    isim = comboBox1.Text;
    yapilacak_is = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    bolum = comboBox2.Text.Trim();
    tarih = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
    durum = comboBox3.Text;
    int idm = Convert.ToInt32(gelenid);
    baglanti.Open();
    komut.Connection = baglanti;
    komut.CommandText = @"UPDATE Bakim SET [Ad]=@isim, 
                    [Bolum]=@bolum,
                    [Yapilacak_Is]=@yapis,          
                    [Tarih]=@tarihim,
                    [Durum]=@durum 
                    WHERE [Id]=@Id";

    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isim", isim);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yapis", yapilacak_is);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bolum", bolum);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarih", tarih);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@durum", durum);
    // Moved after the Cover parameter
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", idm);
    komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```